# td:before and vertical-align:middle

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I use this construction to get table with square cells:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td:before {
    content: '';
    padding-top: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

But vertical-align doesn't work for cell's content.
How can I fix that?

html is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FU84y/1/

Comment: Put your code on Fiddle for us to test

Comment: You are adding a padding-top:100% that causes the issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
float: left;
```

with

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8jPT5/2/

Comment: Nice, didn't know that :)

Comment: Nice one but works only for single line contents. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jPT5/3/)..

Comment: It does't work if cell include other elements [http://jsfiddle.net/eNFDS/](http://jsfiddle.net/eNFDS/)

Comment: @Mr_Green - correct. But that isn't part of the question. We can add support for multiple lines, but we need to add a wrapper element. See http://jsfiddle.net/8jPT5/4/

Comment: @user3713915: I edited my solution to take that into account. Check.

Comment: @Alohci nice +1'ed :)

Answer (score 1):

you need remove `padding-top: 100%;` to td:before
[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rtLes)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  height: 50px;
}
td:before {
    content: '';
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to remove the padding, You need to give the table cell a height.

```
table {
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 40px;

}
td:before {
content: '';
float: left;
padding:100%;
}
```

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LxKP/) example